# Setting Up Rails Models And Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a companies table and a status_codes table
A company can only have one status_code

```
COMPANIES
  id int PK
  name varchar
  status_code_id int FK

STATUS_CODES
id PK
name varchar   (Live, Inactive, Deleted)
```

I am trying to set this up in rails with the following models/associations

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status_code
end

class StatusCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The problem occurs with the `belongs_to :company`, it is expecting the foreign key `company_id` in the `status_codes` table...

I basically want all the status codes in one table so if i need to change a status code name I only change it once and all companies show the newly updated status code name...

Can I setup rails with my database table layout or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you need StatusCode have a has_many :companies.  This way once you'll change a status code all the companies would show the newly updated status code name.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status_code
end

class StatusCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

Of cause, you would need status_code_id foreign key in your companies table.

Comment: Thanks for this, what is the rails way of doing this ? Doesn't really read right StatusCode has_many :companies

Comment: It may not read right at first, but if you think about it in term of OO there's nothing really wrong with it,you just code for what you want to achieve. This also doesn't go against "the rails way" as it is a simple has_many association.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that the side of the association which contains the foreign key should have `belongs_to :other_model`, and the reverse should have the `has_many`.